# How can I make a filter that permanently deletes emails?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In Gmail I have a filter that automatically moves all the mails from one address to the trash folder. I want to permanently delete them by even skipping that folder.

How can I block all messages from an email address so that I'm not even able to read them?

Comment: are they spam, or do you just want to ignore a single person?

Comment: I want to ignore a single persone. I already move all his mails to the Tresh folder with a filter, but still they stay there for 30 days

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Gmail filters are only able to do a normal delete. So, seems you can't achieve what you want using standard Gmail features.

You have to manually empty the trash.